# Ionic serve - 404 when accessing the server

Tags: ionic-framework

I have a nodejs server and ionic client.
When I run my server with "node ." and go to http://localhost:3000/#/login everything works fine.

When I run my client with "ionic server" the application loads in my browser and I see my login screen, but when I enter the details and click login I see in my chrome debug console :

[image]

I notices that the same happens for any button that needs to send a request to the server.

I tried adding `<allow-navigation href="*">` to my config.xml and it didn't help, also tried to play with the ip and port with no luck.

Any idea how I can solve this?

Comment: `ionic serve` is serving the files on which port?

Comment: be default it was 8081, my node.js server is on 3000 so i tried to ionic server with "--port 3000" and it still doesn't work

Comment: i tried "ionic address" to select different address, tried all addresses, doesn't work

Comment: `ionic serve --port 3000` would probably not work before that port is already taken by the node process. 

Follow [this](https://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html) guide, and see if the request from ionic client is reaching your node backend.